# No suitable driver found error even if the my-sql connector uploaded into the library

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection

I am new to java and in a learning process. I'm working on connecting my JDE with MySql and I have followed every step necessary. but when I run the code, I got " No suitable driver found for jdbc.mysql://localhost:3306/dbname" error. I reviewed questions already in stackoverflow and other sources; but the provided solution didn’t work for me.
Any suggestions why i got this error even if I uploaded the mysql-connector-j-8.0.31/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar.[a screenshot of my code and the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChVWd.jpg)

```
package JDBC;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Connection;



public class JDBC {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
        String url = "jdbc.mysql://localhost:3306/University";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "root";
        String query = "select * from EngineeringStudents";
                
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            //To do auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
            
            while(result.next()) {
                String UniversityData = "";
                for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
                    UniversityData += result.getString(i) + ":";
                }
                System.out.println(UniversityData);
            }
            
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your URL - change `jdbc.mysql...` to `jdbc:mysql...` (a colon not a period).

Comment: It's not an error, but you can (and should) also remove the `Class.forName(...)` line of code - and the `try...catch` in which it is placed. `Class.forName(...)` is only needed in some _very_ specific circumstances - and this is not one of them. The chances are good that you may _never_ need `Class.forName(...)` for any of your JDBC driver usage. You can research this separately. It used to be needed, a long time ago... many tutorials still include it.

Comment: Thank you! Problem Solved! The problem was the period that I used instead of colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro use  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/University". Use have missed a colon ':' after jdbc instead you're using '.'